# Android OpenGl: How change single TextureView bitmap?

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

I have a list of photos in my activity.
I should render those concurrently. so I find the best way to have 3 TextureView at first and change the position of them on scrolling the list. If I create EGLThread each time, It runs correctly, but it has a little delay to update the texture. so I need to have EGLThreads permanently, but I don't know to change the bitmap of each EGLThread. I try so many codes but I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Do you really need EGL to render photos?

Comment: yes, I do. It's a app for editing photos and videos and has many filters. if the list just shows one cell each time it was easy but I need to render at least 3 cells at same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.
should run code in postRunnable in EGLThread